# Real time communication between clients via websocket server on Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, websocket

[This](https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/node-js-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial-2def3a841b61) article describes how a websocket server for a chat application can look. We are planning to implement something similar; when a message is sent to the server it is sent to the correct recipient based on an authentication token and the message gets saved in a mysql database.

We will eventually host the server on Google App Engine, and I suspect that that will cause some issues with the above described approach, since that depends on all clients being connected to the same server, and that probably won't be the case since multiple instances will be created as needed. Is there a way to connect all instances so that this won't be a problem (Pub/Sub maybe? (That will cause additional costs though)), or should we find a different solution?

One idea I had was to use [mysql-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events) to monitor the binlog from the websocket server for the creation of new rows in the messages table, but I read somewhere that that wasn't recommend. But I can't find where I read that, and maybe that is the best solution.

Comment: This question comes up a couple of times a week... Mysql is a relational database, not a message broker or a message queue. Use something that was designed for this purpose, like redis or rabbitmq, or one of the message broker solutions provided by gcp.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to search for similar questions, but I didn't find any. Maybe I should have broadened my search... Thank you for your suggestions anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about other solutions, I would recommend looking at Firebase and specifically the Realtime Database.  Out of the box it provides all of the functionality that you need for realtime communication between connected clients and Cloud Messaging for clients who aren't.

[Here's a tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#0) that uses Firestore to create a realtime chat web app, but it can all be applied to the Realtime Database with minor modification.  I say that because Firestore has expensive writes, which in my opinion make it unsuitable for a chat backend.

Comment: We have used Firestore for a similar project before, and that has worked well. Since we need the ability to have multiple databases, Realtime Database seems like a good option. I was kind of hoping that we could keep the messaging part in the same database as everything else, but I see how that will be difficult

Comment: On more than one project I use RTDB as a presentation layer, where a backend relational database acts as the store of truth and some of the data is added to RTDB to be displayed on the frontend.  Think long processing jobs where the status gets periodically updated.  It's easy to display the status changes in realtime with RTDB.

Comment: That's a good idea. Do you think I could listen to updates to RTDB on the websocket server, and then notify the user via that? Our would I just be fighting Firebase then? Would it be better to connect RTDB directly to the application?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not understanding what the purpose of the websocket server in this architecture.  If your goal is a chat app that saves the chat to a MySQL database, I would set up the app like in that tutorial and then create a RTDB trigger that fires on each change that updates the MySQL database.  RTDB handles the realtime push updates to connected clients so no idea where the websocket server fits in.  Good luck!